# Apollo Angular: How do I 'reinitate' my my watchQuery even after an error?

Tags: angular, apollo, apollostack, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

I have a query that searches for an object with a given $ID. It will always fail on the initial page load as we need to wait for the user to provide this $Id. I want my query to continue retrying until a correct Id is found.

Right now the error goes straight through to the error block in subscribe. I have tried multiple approaches including refetch and retry but these don't seem to work.

Please help!

```js
let SingleAPNObs;
let SingleAPNSub;

ngOnInit() {

// Setting up my watch parameters.
let watchVariables: WatchQueryOptions = {
                        query: GQAPNProfile,
                        variables: {
                            _id: this.singleAPN._id
                        }                        
                  };              

this.SingleAPNObs = this.apollo.watchQuery(watchVariables);

this.SingleAPNSub = this.SingleAPNObs
           .subscribe(({data,loading})=> {
                 this.singleAPN = data['apn'];
                 this.single_apn_loading = loading;
            }, (error) => {
                  console.log(error);
            });
                            
 }
```

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?